# How to pass OAuth token to fetch web map without passing userid?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, authentication, web-mapping

I'm using the ArcGIS JavaScript API 3.7 for web map service. The web map is based on Oauth2 authentication. I use java code to fetch the token. Then I need to fetch the map in javascript by calling esri.arcgis.utils.createMap(). But How to pass the token with this request?

I know ArcGIS JavaScript 3.7 offers an API called esri.IdentityManager.registerToken() that can pass the token will the request. But this method requires the user name as parameter. I don't want to put the username in the javascript code, as it's not safe.

Are there any other ways to pass the token with the request?

The api for esri.IdentityManager.registerToken() is **[here](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/identitymanagerbase-amd.html#registertoken)**.

Comment: did you ever get this to work? Even using the username? (I don't mind using username as only exposed when user themselves is logged on via server-side process)